# What should I do when my memory card stops working in my camera and computer?

Tags: memory-card

I have a Canon 7D and it has completely stopped reading my 64GB Sandisk memory card. I don't think the issue is a bent pin because the camera reads other cards fine. When I insert the card into my Macbook Pro it doesn't even show up. I have investigated this problem on many sites and threads and haven't found any conclusive answers. Could anyone tell me what I should try?

Comment: One reason I don't buy 64GB CF cards for cameras. If it goes bad you must replace all 64GB. And two 32GB cards *plus* a replacement (should one ever go bad) are usually cheaper than a single 64GB card of the same speed.

Comment: every card will eventually die, you going to buy a stack of 256MB cards to minimize the loss?

Comment: Try to use some friends computer. There is a chance other equipment can read it. If it does back it up on that same moment.

Answer (score 6):

The card won't read in the camera or in a computer, but both devices will read other cards? Sounds like a dead card to me.

Time to get a new card.

Comment: Or two 32GB cards so that if one goes bad you'll still have the other until you can replace the bad one.

Comment: I have a multitude of cards from 2GB to 32GB, so that's a valid point that I hadn't thought of...

Answer (score 0):

Quiet possible that a data recovery lab could still retrieve your photos. They will have equipment that can recover the data on the card. Usually, the only thing preventing them from doing that, is if the card is toast.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between a card being unreadable in camera and computer, and a card being "toast"?